# WordPress display Role Name not ID

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

The answers I saw were outdated. So I am asking again.

This code

```
<?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  echo '' . implode(', ', $current_user->roles) . "\n";
   ?>
```

returns the Role Name ID "Not" The given or display name
I need this to show the "Display Role Name"

Answer (score 0):

`$current_user->roles` returns an array, with the role name as the value in the key=>value pair.

```
<?php

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if(!empty($current_user->roles)) {
    echo $current_user->roles[0];
}

?>
```

If you have multiple roles assigned via code, you will need to loop through `$current_user->roles` and echo each one.